# Intel NUC wake from suspend with black screen

Tags: suspend

I am trying to get my intel nuc running a celeron processor with 13.10 to wake from suspend. When I press the power button I can hear the computer come to life but nothing activates on my screen?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug, read the workaround at this link
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-power-manager/+bug/1259339

Comment: If there's a workaround, please include it here then provide the link for reference.